# mongodb index for $exists

Tags: mongodb

Given documents shaped like:

```
 { "some-blob-id": {
   { "error": "Some Error Message",
      "data": BinaryData(0, all-that-glop),
      "timestamp" : "time-for-completion-or-error"
   },
   ...
 }
```

and a desire to query for `$exists` of some-blob-id.data, what's the appropriate index spec? I don't want it building an index on that binary stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I would set another field to be 1 when you set data (this is easy enough to backfill). Then add a sparse index on this new field.That is probably the most optimal way to do it.